# Why didn't I initialize the private data member in class successfully?

Tags: c++, oop, class

Now, I faced with an exercise problem: Deal with some data in a class CRect. But my results are different from what I expected.

My code is as followed:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
class CRect
{
public:
    void Diagonal(CRect one)
    {
        float l;
        l=sqrt( (one.right-one.left)*(one.right-one.left)+(one.bottom-one.top)*(one.bottom-one.top) );
        cout<<"The length is "<<l<<endl;
    }
    void Show(CRect one)
    {
        cout<<"("<<one.left<<","<<one.top<<")"<<"   ";
        cout<<"("<<one.right<<","<<one.bottom<<")"<<endl;
    }
    CRect(float left1,float top1,float right1,float bottom1)
    {
        left=left1;
        top=top1;
        right=right1;
        bottom=bottom1;
    }
    CRect(float left1,float top1)
    {
        left=left1;
        top=top1;
    }
    CRect(CRect &c)           
    {
        right=c.right;
        bottom=c.bottom;
    }
private:
    float left,top,right,bottom;
};

int main()
{
    CRect r1(10,10,20,20);
    CRect r2(0,0);
    r2=CRect(r1);
    r1.Show(r1);
    r1.Diagonal(r1);
    r2.Show(r2);
    r2.Diagonal(r2);
    return 0;
}
```

Then，the result is as the following picture:
[image: the result picture]

I think that I have not initialized the `left` and `top` . But, I don't know how to correct it. I can't find the mistake in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your copy constructor only "initializes"<sup>1</sup> `right` and `bottom`, `top` and `left` are left with garbage values:

```
CRect(CRect &c)           
{
    right=c.right;
    bottom=c.bottom;
}
```

Next, this two parameter constructor has similar flaws:

```
CRect(float left1,float top1)
{
    left=left1;
    top=top1;
}
```

You have to set all the data members to something. If you do so, you can completely remove the copy constructor and let the compiler synthesized one do its job.

<sup>1</sup>*why the inverted commas? Because you are actually assigning values to data members that, at least semantically, have already been initialized. To initialize data members to a value, use the constructor initialization list:*`CRect(float left1,float top1) : left(left1), top(top1), right(), bottom() {}`

Answer (score 2):

Your copy constructor `CRect(CRect &c)` fails to initializer left and top. The copy constructor is called When you pass `r1` and `r2` to to the function `Diagonal` and `Show`.

Moreover:

1. You don't need to define a copy-constructor at all. A default one is generated if you don't define your own.
2. `Show` and `Diagonal` are member functions, they don't need to take a parameter.

Comment: Your two points in the "Moreover" is useful. I have known it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized all members in `CRect(float left1,float top1)` constructor and your copy-constructor.

```
CRect(const CRect &c) 
{
    right=c.right;
    bottom=c.bottom;
    top=c.top;
    left=c.left;
}
```

Or even omit your copy-constructor and allow default copy-constructor do everything.

More

```
CRect(float left1,float top1)
{
    left=left1;
    top=top1;
    // How about right and bottom ?!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your copy constructor

```
CRect(CRect &c)           
{
    right=c.right;
    bottom=c.bottom;
}
```

should be

```
CRect(CRect &c)           
{
    right=c.right;
    bottom=c.bottom;
    top=c.top;
    left=c.left
}
```

Comment: And the next step is to remove it, because it doesn't do anything that the compiler generated one wouldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

My answer doesn't directly address your question, but you'll want to get in the habit of using **initialization lists** with your constructors to initialize your class member member variables. *(I say this recognizing that initialization lists may not yet have been introduced in your class.)*

For example, instead of ***assigning*** values to your member variables from your constructor like this:

```cpp
CRect(float left1, float top1)
{
    left=left1;
    top=top1;
}
```

...you should instead ***initialize*** your member variables like this:

```cpp
CRect(float left1, float top1)
    : left(left1), top(top1)
{
}
```

For why, see the C++ FAQ entry [[10.6] Should my constructors use "initialization lists" or "assignment"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html)  as well as [C++ initialization lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists) on SO.

In your own programming, you may also want to consider adopting a naming convention for your member variables to more easily distinguish them from other variable types. For example, instead of:

```cpp
private:
    float left;       // no decoration
```

...consider using one of two common conventions:

```
private:
    float left_;      // trailing underscore
    float m_left;     // leading 'm_'
```

For more about this, see [Trailing underscores for member variables in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650623/trailing-underscores-for-member-variables-in-c) on SO.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your advice. I will go to see the FAQ.