# Missing convention for C++ accessors?

Tags: c++, class, coding-style, getter-setter

I've read the community wiki quetion about the [3 different conventions for accessor methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647438/conventions-for-accessor-methods-getters-and-setters-in-c/3649082#3649082_) and was supmetwhat surprised not to see the following convention:

```
const unsigned& amount() const { return _amount; }
unsigned& amount() { return _amount; }
```

true, it's not quite the same as seamless as being able to avoid the parentheses altogether () - which would (I feel) be idea - but it's still something; right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It defeats the purpose of accessors.  If you provide the two
functions, you might as well make the data member public and be
done with it.

EDIT:

Just to make things perfectly clear: there *are* cases where
using a C style `struct` is the most appropriate solution.  In
those cases, you make the data members public, and don't worry
about accessors.  For classes with significant behavior, on the
other hand, you won't have accessors at all, or very few.  For
the most part, the internal state is *not* reflected directly at
the public interface (and that state which is is usually read
only).  About the only time you'd have need for accessors is for
classes which are basically data, but which must enforce
invariants across the data,

(And for what it's worth: if the data is logically an attribute
of the class, I use:

```
int amount() const { return myAmount; }
void amount( int newValue ) { myAmount = newValue; }
```

For getters of values which are not logically attributes,
however, I'll use `getAmount()`.)

Comment: +1 - A-MEN!  The evils of public data members are *greatly* exaggerated.

Comment: @JohnDibling It depends on the context.  In practice, I find that I do have a number of classes that are really just structures, with all data members public.  And a number of others with no public data members.

Comment: The accessors would at least make it easier to switch to complex getters and setters later on.

Comment: @NeilKirk Not if they return references.  If the role and the responsibility of the class is to hold independent attibutes, and nothing else, then switching to getters or setters which do something else will break client code.

Comment: @NeilKirk - violating engineering principles like YAGNI seems like a poor reason to use accessors.

Comment: @hoodaticus For example, later on I may want to add asserts to a setter to check for invalid values - values which may always have been invalid per the documentation, but never before checked. This is easier to add later if you used accessors.

Answer (score 2):

The second of your examples gives the user access to the original `_amount` in the class, without any form of protection from the class itself. The purpose of "encapsulation", which is an important aspect of OOP is to ensure that all the accesses to a variable is done within the class itself - that way the class can control the value range or other validity.

If you want the class to transparently allow the user to use `amount`, then call it `amount` and make it public. There is no need for accessor functions then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that it can defeat the purpose of a getter/setter convention. If you're passing a mutable reference to the private member, you might as well expose the member and remove the hassle of function calls.

Also, I found this syntax very ugly and unreadable, but that's my personal taste:

```
foo.amount() = 23;
```