# I have data but it says can not resolve variable "data"

Tags: c++, constructor

We are learning classes and I am doing my assignment to write a class and 5 different objects and to display the difference.

The professor said that we should use default constructors and the book says this:

> A default constructor is a constructor which can be called with no arguments (either defined with an empty parameter list, or with default arguments provided for every parameter).

I am doing exactly what the teacher did; can you please tell me why it says it can't find `data`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class theC
{
private:
    string data;
public:
    theC() {
        printf("default\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    theC c1();
    theC c2();
    theC c3();
    theC c4();
    theC c5();

    c1.data = "different object 1";
    c2.data = "different object 2";
    c3.data = "different object 3";
    c4.data = "different object 4";
    c5.data = "different object 5";
    cout << c1.data << c2.data << c3.data << c4.data << c5.data;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about the [member access specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access), what it means when a class member is `private`.

Comment: And `theC c1();` is function declaration. Change it to `theC c1;`, same for others.

Comment: [access specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access)

Comment: Ahh, another victim of the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: Why using `printf` instead of `cout`? "Also I don't think you deserve any down vote"

Comment: I copy paste it from the professor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has several issues:

**Issue one**: Is in these lines:

```
theC c1();  
theC c2();      
theC c3();  
theC c4();  
theC c5();
```

Here you are trying to declare an instance(object) of your class `theC`. However, your compiler considers it as a *[Function Declaration](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/yAqpX9L8/)* and the *Prototype* of a function called `c1` that takes zero or no parameters(`()` is empty) and returns an object of type `theC`.

The correct syntax for declaring an object of your class would : `theC c1;`

So your Default Constructor **will** be called as soon as you declare a variable of your class. It is how it works.

**Issue two:** Also, you can not access **any** "*Private*" member. You would need it to be "Public" or you would need to use [getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647438/conventions-for-accessor-methods-getters-and-setters-in-c).

**Issue three:**
You are using a the `string` class without `#include <string>`.

Comment: I did it and it works but it displays everything on one line do you know why?

Comment: Your code does **exactly** how you wrote it: `cout << c1.data << c2.data << c3.data << c4.data << c5.data;`

Comment: @Nope Use constructions cout << c1.data << '\n' << c2.dara << '\n' and so on

Answer (score 2):

These declarations

```
int main()
{
    theC c1();
    theC c2();
    theC c3();
    theC c4();
    theC
    c5();
 //..
```

declare functions c1, c2, c3, c4 and c5 with return type `theC` and with no parameters.

Write instead

```
int main()
{
    theC c1;
    theC c2;
    theC c3;
    theC c4;
    theC
    c5;
 //...
```

Also you should at least include headers `<string>` and `<cstdio>` because the program uses declarations from these headers.

Take into account that data member `data`  is declared as private. So you may not access it directly outside the class definition like

```
c1.data = "different object 1";
c2.data = "different object 2";
c3.data = "different object 3";
c4.data = "different object 4";
c5.data = "different object 5";
```

Comment: Why the `<cstdio>`?

Comment: @FirstStep I wrote that at least... He uses standard C function printf in the constructor.

Comment: @FirstStep Some compilers can compile the code without header <string>. However it is a bad approach.