# Primitive data type overloaded is this correct?

Tags: c++, setter, getter, accessor

I am fairly new to C++ (from a Java background) and I am working on a project for myself to keep track of stocks. I created a class called `Stock` that has a `double` variable called `shareVal` which represents the price of a share of stock. Since `shareVal` can never be negative, I then created a `SharePrice` class to perform the type checking:

```
class SharePrice
{
private:
    double shareVal;
public:
    SharePrice();
    SharePrice(double price);
    double getPrice() const { return shareVal; }
    void setPrice(double price);
};

SharePrice::SharePrice()
{
    setPrice(0);
}

SharePrice::SharePrice(double price)
{
    setPrice(price);
}

void SharePrice::setPrice(double price)
{
    if (price > 0)
        shareVal = price;
    else
        shareVal = 0;
}
```

This is the style I would use in Java, but after reading this [Conventions for accessor methods (getters and setters) in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647438/conventions-for-accessor-methods-getters-and-setters-in-c), I understand that this might be bad form in C++. Is this style appropriate? Is there an easier/better (C++) way of doing the same thing?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with *overloading*.

Comment: why not formalize the data requirements in the type ? Eg. use an `unsigned` integer type of your desired width, and a fixed-point representation ? This would also avoid many of the issues you'll encounter when using a floating point representation for monetary values.

Comment: Note that you should never represent money in floating point, due to potential rounding errors.

Comment: the easiest way is use a raw double and trust it will not be negative. (or at most check when really *need*)

Comment: The reason I used the term "overloaded" is because I am using the double data type with different parameters (can't be negative). Hence why I wanted to create the class and perform the type checking. Is there a different term for this? That was my understand of overloaded.

Comment: _overloading_ generally refers to overloaded functions, i.e. multiple functions with the same name but different parameters. Other than that, this question seems somewhat subjective. I think your approach is fine since you actually perform a check on the argument passed to your setter which you obviously couldn't do if it was public.